# How to Build form action url with 'sec:authentication="name"' in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-thymeleaf

example: <form th:action="@{/hello/${#authentication.username}}"

try to pass authentication.username as a parameter to the controler

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't use the username like this for anything security related. You shouldn't need to do this any way. The server should know the logged in user itself. There is no need to send the name to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with 
 `<form th:action="@{/hello/{id}/(id=${#authentication.getName()})}">`

Thymeleafs [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) on standard url syntax explains how to add parameters as path variable or request parameters in pretty detailed manner. 

 Added this answer only for learning purpose. You don't need to send username like this. Access it on server side from authentication principal.

Comment: @PostMapping("/{id}") //"/{email}"
 private String addnew(@ModelAttribute("fuser") UserDTO dto,@PathVariable String id)     now this is not working properly could you help.                                                                                           Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 14 10:37:37 CDT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Please edit your question and post the controller mapping code there

Comment: @PostMapping("/{id}") 
 private String addnew@PathVariable("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("food") FoodDTO dto) {  
  findByEmail(id);
  return "foods";
 }

Comment: this is what I am getting:  Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Tue Mar 14 10:37:37 CDT 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available

Comment: Did you miss /hello in controller mapping